# OnPress change VIEW content

Tags: react-native, button, view

I want to have two tab buttons on top and some content underneath.

After that, the content I need a View like this :

```
<Form style={styles.form}>
    <Label style={styles.label}>
        data 1
    </Label>
    <Item >
        <Input/>
    </Item>
    <Label style={styles.label}>
        Data2
    </Label>
    <Item>
        <Input/>
    </Item>
</Form>
```

When I clicking on the first button, it is active. I need that form to appear.
After that, when I clicking on the second button, I need that form change to:

```
<Form style={styles.form}>
    <Label style={styles.label}>
        data 3
    </Label>
    <Item >
        <Input />
    </Item>
</Form>
```

What I'm understanding is that I need a state variable.

```
state = {showFirst : true, showSecond:false }
```

and have somewhere a conditional:

```
if showFirst true, display FORM1
if showSecond true, display FORM2
```

And

```
onPress {() => {this.setState{{the state = true)}}
```

But I am not sure how to bind this together as I'm using React Native for the first time.
Currently what I'm using now is it a good practice?
I set separate states variables for both forms, because another button may be added later.
So I can't only one button:

```
state = { showForm: true}
showForm?Form1:Form2
onPress={() => {this.setState{{showForm:false)}}
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

This is a minimum example Component for what you said you were trying to achieve:

```
import React, {Component} from ‘react’;
import {Button, View} from ‘react-native’;

export default class ExampleComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         showForm: 0
      };
    }

      render() {
         var form;
         if (this.state.showForm === 0) {
            form = (
               <View> INSERT_FORM1 </View>
            );
         } else if (this.state.showForm === 1) {
            form = (
               <View> INSERT_FORM2 </View>
            );
         }

         return (
            <View>
               <Button title=‘Show Form 1’ onPress={() => this.setState({showForm: 0})}/>
               <Button title=‘Show Form 2’ onPress{() => this.setState({showForm: 1})}/>
               {form}
            </View>
         );
      }
}
```

You can dynamically choose what content to show based on the Component props and state.
In the example above I used a numerical value to determine what form to show to minimize the amount of state values you would have to track later if the form count expanded.
A switch statement would be a better choice in the event of more available form choices, but I used if-else here for easy of typing for now.